# Importing / Converting U3D files

Tags: 3d

I have a [Universal 3D File](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_3D) - but I cannot find any way to view or convert it in Linux.

Here's what I've tried:

- [Meshlab](https://sourceforge.net/p/meshlab/discussion/499532/thread/da02c8bc/) won't import
- [Blender](https://web.archive.org/web/20200924220026/https://www.blender.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=17757) won't import
- [FreeCAD](https://github.com/FreeCAD/FreeCAD) won't import

If the file is embedded in a PDF, I can view it using Adobe Reader 9 - but there's no way to export it.

Ideally I'd like to be able to convert it to STL - but any common 3D format would do.

Has anyone found or built a converter?

Comment: See also https://sourceforge.net/p/meshlab/patches/1/

Comment: Blender claims to support U3D, See: https://www.file-extension.info/downloads/blender

Comment: Blender says it will export U3D, but I have not been able to get it to work in Ubuntu or Windows?